# jQuery foreach guidance

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

I'm trying to come up with some kind of **foreach** loop that'd cycle through some hidden values on page, compare it with external api through ajax and print the api results in < ul > f.ex.

### Example model

```
ITEM1
    metavalue (which needs to be queried agains API)
/ITEM1
ITEM2
    metavalue (in case there's more ITEMS on the page I need the foreaach loop)
/ITEM2
```

... and so on

- How do I have to identify objects on the page so I can properly loop
  through them?
- How can I position resulting list from API? (If there are records.)
- In case the script couldn't fire on page load, can I bind it to a
  button?

Comment: All what you need can be found at jQuery docs.

Comment: to add to what @Adam Azad stated, look into AJAX to pull back the records (that way no page refresh will be needed)

Comment: You can use a class to identify the objects you want to cycle through. Use DOM traversal functions relative to `$(this)` to position a result for each input item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide information in `data` field i.e. `<div data-foo="bar"></div>`, and loop through them with `$('.some-class).each($(this.data('foo'))`

```
<div class="hid" data-foo="bar1">
<div class="hid" data-foo="bar2">
<div class="hid" data-foo="bar3">
$('.hid').each(function() { console.log($(this).data('foo'))});
```

Then you send multiple ajax request, and after return all of them (details here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) you create html string in loop and append it to some `<div id="result></div>`

```
var list = '<ul>';
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    list += '<li>' + res[i] + '</li>';
}
list += '</ul>'
$('#result).append(list);
```

You can use `window.onload` to load script, or bind with button with `$('#button-id').on('click', runFunction);`